# Responsive with max-width em is not work

Tags: html, css, responsive

I create a landing page base on this template.

I use something like:

`@media (max-width: 43.75em)`

I open Chrome Dev Tools to check on the mobile device but seem it not go to `@media (max-width: 43.75em)`.

to responsive but it not working.

I tested in my localhost:

[image]

With same code, it tested on Codepen or JSFiddle, it works.

I don't know the problem in my case:

[image]

You can access in my pen, choose `Export as .zip` to show in localhost:

https://codepen.io/vanloc/pen/zEBdJy

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,300);
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: #141414;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background: #007ece;
    letter-spacing: .02em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .8rem 1rem .9rem;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #008ee8;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:focus:active {
    background: #006eb5;
    border-color: #006eb5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
}

header {
    color: white;
    background: #007ece;
    padding: 10rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

header h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

section {
    background: #fff;
    color: #1c262b;
    padding: 3.5rem 0;
}

section.section--primary {
    background: #007ece;
    color: #fff;
}

section.section--primary--alt {
    background: #27a4f4;
    color: #fff;
}

section.section--primary--light {
    background: rgba(0, 126, 206, 0.1);
}

section.section--grey {
    background: #1c262b;
    color: #fff;
}

section.section--grey--light {
    background: #29363e;
    color: #fff;
}

section h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

section li {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

section p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.col,
.col-7,
.col-3,
.col-5 {
    margin: 0 1.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.col-7 {
    width: 64%;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 29%;
}

.col-5 {
    width: 30%;
}

.details {
    text-align: left;
}

.details h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: left;
}

.features {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.features:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.features i {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
}

.features p {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

blockquote {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

blockquote:before {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #007ece;
    font-size: 2rem;
    content: '\201C';
}

blockquote p {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

blockquote cite {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    margin: .5rem 0 0 1.2rem;
    text-style: italic;
}

blockquote cite:before {
    content: '–';
}

footer {
    background: #2d2b2a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

footer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

footer ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: .4rem .7rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

footer ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.text--center {
    text-align: center;
}

.text--left {
    text-align: left;
}

.bg-image {
    background: #007ece;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-image:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #333 url("http://orbotix.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Faster-4H5B55491.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    opacity: .8;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.bg-image.bg-image-2:before {
    opacity: .6;
    background-image: url("http://orbotix.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Kids3.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
}

@media (max-width: 43.75em) {
    .btn {
        padding: .5rem .7rem .6rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    header {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }
    header h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    header h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    section {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }
    section h3 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .col-7 {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .col-3 {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .col-5 {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .details-img--ball {
        height: 200px;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .features {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    .features:last-child {
        border: none;
    }
    .features i {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        width: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
        float: left;
    }
    .features p {
        margin-left: 3rem;
    }
    blockquote p {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    blockquote cite {
        font-size: .8rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<header class="bg-image">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Awesome Product</h1>
    <h2>Dat product subline is so nice it blows your mind.</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-transparent">Order yours now!</a>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-3 text--center">
      <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4044/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/H/D1/HD162/HD162?wid=800&hei=800&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1400749861094" alt="" class="details-img--ball"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 details">
      <h3>Product is so awesome.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere temporibus omnis illum, officia. Architecto voluptatibus commodi voluptatem perspiciatis eos possimus, eius at molestias quaerat magnam? Odio qui quos ipsam natus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section--primary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-3 features">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
      <p>
        Product so awesome. Makes you awesome - go buy!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 features">
      <i class="fa fa-bank"></i>
      <p>
        Product so great. Makes you even greater - go buy now. Super cheap deal!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 features">
      <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
      <p>
        Feel lonely? Go buy product and have a friend! 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section--primary--alt">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Take Product with you everywhere you go.</h3>
    <p>Product is all you need. Anywhere - ever. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sapiente hic voluptatum quo sunt totam accusamus distinctio minus aliquid quis!</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section--primary--light">
  <div class="container">
    <blockquote class="testimonial">
      <p>Love product. So nice! So good! Could not live without!</p>
      <cite>
        Satisfied Customer
      </cite>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="section--primary--alt bg-image bg-image-2">
  <div class="container text--center">
    <h3>Reasons to buy this product:</h3>
    <div class="col-5 text--left">
      <ul>
        <li>Its the best</li>
        <li>Its awesome</li>
        <li>It makes you happy</li>
        <li>It brings world peace</li>
        <li>Its free!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 text--left">
      <ul>
        <li>Its the best</li>
        <li>Its awesome</li>
        <li>It makes you happy</li>
        <li>It brings world peace</li>
        <li>Its free!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text--center">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Why you still reading?</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Order yours now!</a>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mainpage</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>&copy; 2014 dat Company. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Works for me... and I'm using Chrome

Comment: hi, @FlorinPop, I updated my question. If you check on Codepen, Stack quick view or JsFiddle. it's will working. Can you try to download in Codepen link and test on your local environment?

Comment: you can try this way 
       @media (max-device-width: 43.75em){
}

Comment: @Md.Shahjalal can you explain why using `max-device-width` in my case?

Comment: In CSS media the difference between width and device-width can be a bit muddled, device-width refers to the width of the device itself, the screen resolution of the device. though device-width is useful when you wish to specifically target mobile devices

Comment: @Md.Shahjalal if using `max-device-width`. in same device `nexus 5x`. it should show like https://i.imgur.com/3qWPmtX.png. But I receive like https://i.imgur.com/KMpBiPQ.png. I don't know problem at here.

Comment: if its not remove i suggest you can use pixel @media (max-device-width:778px){} write your css in-line here its work fine